# filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole always returns false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I have a ASP.NET MVC3 base controller that overrides `OnAuthorization`.

Inside it I need to check if a user belongs to a group or not. I try to do this using the following code:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Administrators")
```

This always returns `false`. This code is quite old, and I know it worked a long time ago, but ther has been lots of changes to the application since then.

I have checked that `filterContext.HttpContext.User` is the user I expect it to be. The only thing that seems strange to me is that `filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Groups` only consist of (at least to me) strange occurences. There are 12 in total, and all of them are named like `S-1-1-0`, `S-1-5-32-578`, `S-1-11-96-3623454863-58364-18864-2661722203-1597581903-1925228150-393568358-393553007-2220982628-3283586193` and so on.

Basically, I'm using MVC3, Windows Authentication and needs to know if the current user belongs to a specific group or not. What do I do?

Comment: Those entries look like SIDs: the underlying ID that Windows uses to identify users and groups. Normally they would be resolved by Windows into the normal names, but this can fail if either the object (User, Group, …) has been removed (eg. deleted from AD) or there is no communications with AD. Can you resolve them from the command line using something like [`psgetsid`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897417)?

Comment: On my current machine (developer machine where there is no AD set up.) Could it be that this will still work on the production environment, but not on my local development machine? Any way to get this to also work towards my local machine and local users/groups?

Comment: Yes it should work in live (if things are configured to resolve the SIDs), but going live without being able to verify is a risk (of course). It should "just work" with local accounts.